# CollectionView objects (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cell, collectionview

I want the highlight to change the size and appearance of an object inside the collection view.

How can I set object properties in a collection view cell, within the "didHighlight" method?

In "cellForItemAtIndexPath" you declare the reusable cells as the class

and just use "cell.MyOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()"

```html
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewController {
            let (FriendFirstName,FriendLastName) = friends[indexPath.row]
    
            let cell: CustomCellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellA
        
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                cell.cellTitle.text = Name
                cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: Pics[indexPath.row])
            
                cell.imgCell.layer.masksToBounds = true
                cell.self.imgCell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                
                return cell
                
                
            } else {
            
                let cell2: AddCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddCell
                return cell2
            }
        } else if collectionView == self.EmojiCollectionViewController {
            let cellB: CustomCellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCellB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellB
            
            cellB.MyLabel.text = arrayOne[indexPath.row]
            
            return cellB
            
        } else {
            let cellC: CustomCellC = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCellC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellC
            
            // ...Set up cell
            let height = self.CollectionViewController2.frame.height
            
            cellC.frame = CGRectMake(cellB.frame.origin.x, 0, cellB.frame.size.width, height)
            cellC.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
            cellC.layoutIfNeeded()
            cellC.imgVw.image = UIImage(named: pictures[indexPath.row] as! String)

            return cellC
        }
        
    }
```

```html
    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        if collectionView == self.CollectionViewController {
        
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                let cell: CustomCellA = CustomCellB()
                cell.MyLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()  //crashes due to nil value)

            }
        
        } else {
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

I tried using a similar definition in didHighlight and it keeps crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Let `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` only change the data, not the view. So, make `friends[indexPath.row]` an object or add another parameter to tuple. And in `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` do something like the following:

```
 if collectionView == self.CollectionViewController {
     if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let (fname, lname, color) = friends[indexPath.row];

        friends[indexPath.row] = (fname, lname, UIColor.blueColor())
     }     
 }
```

And in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
if collectionView == self.CollectionViewController {
    let (FriendFirstName, FriendLastName, color) = friends[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.section != 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddCell;
        return cell;
    } else if color == nil {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellA;

        cell.cellTitle.text = Name
        cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: Pics[indexPath.row])

        cell.imgCell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.self.imgCell.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        return cell
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCellB", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellB;

        // your code for CustomCellB

        return cell;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Updated, so instead of objects it uses tuples. Also added the functionality that you need. Basically, you need to create two prototype cells in the interface builder with different Reuse Identifiers and Classes. And then dequeue the correct identifier in the index path. Also, I refactored some of your code and if I were you I would create a different function for each collectionView and do something like:

```
if collectionView == self.CollectionViewController {
    return self.dequeueCollectionCell(indexPath);
} else if collectionView == self.EmojiCollectionViewController {
    return self.dequeuEmojiCell(indexPath);
} else {
    return self.dequeueSomeOtherCell(indexPath);
}
```

Also, the code that you provided... I hope it is not an actual production code and you changed the values for this forum. Otherwise, in couple of days even, you are going to get lost in what is happening here. Too many inconsistent variable names and identifiers.

One more also. Use naming conventions in your class names. Read this [forum post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab) for more information. Apple uses camelCase everywhere. In majority of instances, the first letter is capitalized for class names, not object names.

Comment: The issue is that I have a UIView inside the collectionView cell. since the outlet is in a separate class, I cannot use cell.myView.backgroundColor because I cannot define it.

Comment: Also you cannot set a color to a string or an array, that is just the data source, not the UILabel.

Comment: I know you can't that's why I said make friends[indexPath.row] an object or tuple (I used object)

Comment: I don't understand why you would do that. That is just asking for trouble. You have set up the cell's class as CustomCellA in the interface builder, right? So you will have casting issues the moment you do that. But there is a way to achieve this. Create two prototype cells inside the interface builder and then do it through `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define the collectionView Cell then do what ever you want on that cell. to define your sell add the below lines into didHighlightItemAtIndexPath

```
if let cellToUpdate = self.dataCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                                //your code here.
                            }
```

Comment: this does not open the objects for the custom class. I need to alter the frame of an object inside the cell when the cell is highlighted.